# python error with Popen while using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have my python script this

```
var1 = subprocess.Popen("pwd | grep 'home' ");
print var1
```

But it is giving me error

Comment: In addition to the questions above, what're you trying to do?  There's probably a better (built-in) way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `shell=True` if you want the shell to interpret the pipe correctly:

```
var1 = subprocess.Popen("pwd | grep 'home' ", shell=True)
```

(Note that you don't need a semi-colon at the end of the line.)  That might not do what you expect, though - that returns a Popen object so then you need to check whether `var1.wait()` returns `0` or not.

A much easier way, if you just want to find out if the current directory contains 'home', is to do:

```
if 'home' in os.getcwd():
    print "'home' is in the current working directory's path"
```

Comment: i get this  **<subprocess.Popen object at 0xb7ea0a6c>]** . actually i am learing python and i don't know where to start . are there any tutorials which can help me doing linux tasks with python

Comment: http://magazine.redhat.com/2008/02/07/python-for-bash-scripters-a-well-kept-secret/ (2nd link in a Google search for "python bash replacement")